# Young adult book; takes place on a dusty planet where the only food is space potatoes

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, space

I read this book a few years ago; I remember it was in the young adult section of my library. i feel like it was an older book, not quite sure though.

The cover was pink I believe with flowers or plants on it. The book takes place on a different planet with lots of dust I believe. Their only food is space potatoes but they aren't very good. The main character is a young woman I think.

There's an alien breed on the planet. There's a painter who rapes a woman. There's a big fire in the painter's barn. There is a small town with a little shop (possibly). I believe that the planet had lots of crater type holes. There was a romance subplot between the main character and a guy but I don't think they ended up together.

Comment: What do you mean by "functional town?"  As opposed to a dysfunctional one?